# Seeking a combinatorial proof of the identity$n+(n-1)2^1+(n-2)2^2+\cdots+ 2\cdot 2^{n-2}+ 1\cdot 2^{n-1}=-n+2^{n+1}-2$

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem

Q: show that combinatoric identity (using by combinatorial proof)

$$n+(n-1)2^1+(n-2)2^2+\cdots+ 2\cdot 2^{n-2}+ 1\cdot 2^{n-1}=-n+2^{n+1}-2$$

Comment: No source, no motivation, no sign of independent effort. Voting to close. 

Comment: Perfectly good question, don’t care where it came from, voting to reopen.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson : Are you rage-quitting? This website is all about wasting your time answering questions to impolite people, you should know this by now... (no offense, I think OP's question is okay, but I get Gerry's feeling).

Answer (score 1):

LHS and RHS give two ways of counting the number of bit-strings of length $n+1$ with at least two ones in them. Define:
$$M= \{(a_1,\dots,a_{n+1})\in \{0,1\}^{n+1} | \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1}a_i \geq 2\}$$

We prove, $\text{LHS}=|M|=\text{RHS}$.

**RHS**: Then:
$$M=\{0,1\}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}^{n+1} \setminus \{(a_1,\dots,a_{n+1})\in \{0,1\}^{n+1} | \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1}a_i = 1\}$$
So 
$$|M|=2^{n+1}-1-(n+1)=-n+2^{n+1}-2$$

**LHS**: Define $B_k = \{(a_1,\dots,a_{n+1})\in A | \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}a_i = 1 \wedge a_{k+1}=1 \}$ for $k=1,\dots,n$ and $B=\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{n}B_k$.

1. $M=B$. *Proof:* Let $a=(a_1,\dots,a_{n+1})\in M$, this implies, that $k=\min\{i\geq 1\mid a_k=1\}$ is well-defined. Check, that $a\in B_{k-1}$. The converse is clearly true.
2. $B_k \cap B_l=\varnothing$ for $k\neq l$. *Proof:* Assume $a\in B_k\cap B_l$. Wlog, assume $k<l$, then:
   $$1\overset{a\in B_l}{=}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{l}a_i\geq \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k+1}a_i = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}a_i+a_{i+1}\overset{a\in B_k}{=}1+1=2$$
   This is a contradiction.
3. $|B_k|=k\cdot 2^{n-k}$. *Proof:* $a_{k+1}$ is fixed. There are $k$ possibilities for $(a_1,\dots,a_k)$ (since exactly one of them is $1$) and $2^{(n+1)-(k+2)+1}=2^{n-k}$ possibilites for $(a_{k+2},\dots,a_{n+1})$.

So:
$$|M|\overset{1)}{=}|B|=\left|\bigsqcup\limits_{k=1}^{n}B_k\right|\overset{2)}{=}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}B_k\overset{3)}{=}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}k\cdot 2^{n-k}$$

Comment: @Young: A possibly easier way to think about the same idea: Start with the set $S=\{0,1,\dots,n\}$. Pick any $k\in S\setminus\{0\}$ and color it red. There are $k$ ways to choose an $m\in S$ with $m<k$ and color it blue, and there are $2^{n-k}$ ways to pick any subset of the members of $S$ greater than $m$ and color it blue. Summing over $k$ gives you the lefthand side of your identity, and the sum is the number of ways to to paint one element of $S$ red and at least one blue in such a way that exactly one blue element is less than the red one. But that’s just the number of ways ...

Comment: ... to pick a subset of $S$ with at least $2$ elements, color the second smallest one red, and color the rest blue. $S$ has $2^{n+1}$ subsets; $n+1$ of them are singletons, and one is the empty set, so $S$ has $2^{n+1}-(n+2)$ subsets with at least $2$ elements.

Answer (score 1):

This question is actually very similar to [that one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429084/seeking-a-combinatorial-proof-of-the-identity-12-cdot-213-cdot-22-cdotsn), therefore my answer is also similar.

Denote $\left[n\right]=\left\{1,\dots,n\right\}$. Count all pairs $\left(X,k\right)\in2^{\left[n\right]}\times\left[n+1\right]$ where $X\ne\emptyset$ and $k>\max X$ in two ways.

First way: First select $\max X$, then select $k$ and the rest of $X$.

Second way: There is a match between such pairs and $\left\{Y\subseteq\left[n+1\right]\middle|\left|Y\right|\ge2\right\}$ by $\left(X,k\right)\mapsto X\cup\left\{k\right\}$ and $Y\mapsto\left(Y\backslash\max Y,\max Y\right)$.